# node js api design and waiting for long process excution

Tags: javascript, node.js, api-design, node-api

I have 2 tables

1. pin codes - list of pin codes [lets take 5000]
2. addresses - corresponding addresses-from an API

I want to write an API like '/update-addresses' by using Node Js

After updating the required table API should give response back like 'update done'

above scenario was working fine in my case when i am going with 10 pin codes.

**but for 100 or more it's taking too much time to complete. is it will through an error like timed out?**

**how we can reduce the time for 100 or more pin codes?**

algorithm:

```
fun(res,req){
a=list of pin codes 
output=[]
Promise.all(a.map(){
 let p=new Promise((resolve)=>{
   axios(API call).then(d=>{
     resolve(d)
   })
 })
 return p.then(out=>{
   output.push(out)
 })
}).then(()=>{
  res.send(output)
})

}
```

Comment: The bottleneck is clearly on the API call, would you consider to make a batchUpdate API call instead?

Comment: You need to implement something like background task 
fire and forget api and then check the status of the api - you will need extra logic for that

Comment: I can provide you some rough algorithm where I have done similar thing recently
I too had long waiting call which included hitting external API's